# how can I use file .env in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, backend, nest

I've seen the on documentation the steps and did:

1. $ npm i --save @nestjs/config.
2. import the ConfigModule.
   It should work.

I tried to add like this process.env.DB_USER, but I see error.
[image]

```java
@Module({
imports: [
    HttpModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DATA_HOST,
    port: ****,
    username: '*****',
    password: '****',
    database: '****',
    synchronize: true,
    entities: [UserEntity, TutorEntity],
    }),
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
    CategoryModule,
    TutorsModule,
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Do the username and password _also_ come from the `.env` file? What makes you think that's where the failure is? I'd guess that, if you're right, it's a timing problem - `ConfigModule` has not yet actually been loaded at the time you're trying to configure the `TypeOrmModule`.

Comment: I've decided this problem with configService and It's working.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true })` in correct way but make sure your `.env` file is at root level of your project

or optionally, provide the path to your `.env` file in `ConfigModule.forRoot` as shown below:

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
  envFilePath: '../path/to/youENVfile/.env',
});
```

or for providing multiple files

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
  envFilePath: ['.env.development.local', '.env.development'],
});
```